# Settings Proxy Certificate environment variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, proxy, environment-variables

So I just updated vscode to the version 1.44.2

I'm working behind my companies proxy, so I was setting some environment variables like this:

```
"HTTP_PROXY": "http://user:pw@proxy:port",
"REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE": "path/to/proxy/certificate.crt"
```

So that i could install pip packages.

Now since the new vscode update, apparently the synthax has changed. 
`HTTP_PROXY` is now being used as `http.proxy`.
But i don't know how to set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`, as it's always greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want these settings to show up in the terminal for when you run the `pip` command. If that's true then you sent set e.g. `"terminal.integrated.env.linux"` in your settings with these environment variables (change it to specify the OS you are running on).